# Auto increment ID in Realm, Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

After a lot of troubles, i finally got my code converted to Swift 3.0.

But it seems like my incrementID function isn't working anymore?

Any suggestions how i can fix this?

My incrementID and primaryKey function as they look right now.

```
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}

func incrementID() -> Int{
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let RetNext: NSArray = Array(realm.objects(Exercise.self).sorted(byProperty: "id")) as NSArray
    let last = RetNext.lastObject
    if RetNext.count > 0 {
        let valor = (last as AnyObject).value(forKey: "id") as? Int
        return valor! + 1
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There's no need to use KVC here, or to create a sorted array just to get the max value. You can just do:

```
func incrementID() -> Int {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    return (realm.objects(Exercise.self).max(ofProperty: "id") as Int? ?? 0) + 1
}
```

Comment: I feel like this may cause some issue. If you delete the max id object, then add another object the new object's id will be same with the deleted object's id.

Comment: What is the problem with a deleted object's id? Doesn't it mean that the ID is free to use? But for performance issue, you should only query this value once.

Comment: @GüngörBasa is right. This would replace existing object.

Comment: You could mark the object as deleted using a designated (existing or new) field and never allow actual deletions from the database. You retain access to older information and can even possibly reinstate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    use this below example code.
    
    class Dog: Object {
            @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: Int?
            @Persisted var name: String?
            @Persisted var age: Int?
            
            func incrementID() -> Int {

let realm = try! Realm()
                let getvalue = realm.object(Dog.self).map({$0.id!}).last ?? 0
                return getvalue + 1
            }
        }
        
        let dog = Dog()
                dog.name = "Rex"
                dog.age = 1
                dog.id = dog.incrementID()
        
        its keep increase its value in ID
```